# Where to send legal questions about youtube data API

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api

First off, I don't know if this is the right area for this question, but it has the right tag so thought I'd try here. I want to know what the right website or email to send legal questions about the API.

I have tried to look around all the help sites on google and haven't come across anything relating. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For legal support contact information you can visit the following URL:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6154232?hl=en